# Spring-MVC :: How to pass request parameters (or) query string values to another subsequent request?

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, servlets, spring-mvc

I have a scenario to pass values from one request to another subsequent rquest. (i.e) I will call 'Controller1' on the first request and take the request parameters or query string and should send them to 'Controller2' as 'new request'.

Strictly I should not use any of the following approaches.

1. should not use sessions.
2. should not use cookies.
3. should not use requestdispatcher.forward(--).
4. without FlashAttributes (which internally uses session, which won't work in 'Clustered environmnets').
5. should not expose the ModelAttribues in request parameters in case of redirection (i.e) I should not even expose them as request parameters using spring RedirectView.

please let me know, if we have any alternative approch.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You could  call the underlying method directly

So if you have as controller2 :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/MyURL", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String myMethod(final BaseDTO baseDTO, Model model) {}
```

Inject controller2 into controller1 and call "normally":

```
controller2.myMethod(baseDTO, model);
```

Comment: "Inject controller2 into controller1" ew, that smells bad

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd I would be interested in any "less smelly" solution ... refactor th elogic and stick the code in a separate service class ?

Comment: Given the OPs "Strictly I should not use any of the following approaches." List: good luck